# Finding element with jquery in asp

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to set value of textbox with drop down list using jquery, but cant figure out how to find  current textbox.

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
     <div class="row" id="formValidator">
     <div class="col-sm-6">

     <div class="form-group" id="contractGroup">
                    <label for="inputContract" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Contract Type <b>*</b></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Full-time</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Part-time</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <asp:TextBox runat="server" type="text" class="form-control" ID="inputContract" placeholder="Full time, Part time"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
</asp:Content>
```

*Jquery function*

```
    $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu li a', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.asp:TextBox').val($(this).html());
    });
```

Which is probably wrong, I attempted to use `closest()` as well, but to no avail , from my search online I saw people are using made up classes for elements they are trying to find, is that necessary ?

Comment: `find('.asp:TextBox')` won't work because there is no such thing on the client-side. Add a class to the input and use that.

Comment: @AntP already tried that, and I have form-control class associated with my textbox which I would like to keep.

Comment: You can use multiple classes on a single element. If you have tried it, you have not done so properly because it would have solved your problem. You can't select `.asp:TextBox` because there is no such thing.

Comment: @AntP I did mention that my Jquery find is probably wrong in my post, so chances are, I did it wrong, thats why I am asking for help :)

Comment: We have established that what you've posted is wrong but you have said you "already tried" my suggested fix (presumably implying that it didn't work) - without seeing this attempt it is hard to help you further.

Comment: Well If I am looking in a wrong place with my search, it doesnt really matter if item I am looking exists somewhere else or doesnt exist at all. And answer by @Slippery Pete works which shows that my search was wrong in depth and item I am trying to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close.. You have to go up one more parent and look for input type of text:

```
$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('input[type="text"]')
```